# Is there anyway so that when I login to Alfresco instead going to dashboard, it should open the repository page?

Tags: authentication, alfresco, dashboard, login-control

When I login to Alfresco it directly takes me to Dashboard. But I want to open Repository page when I get logged in. Please tell me in which file I need to change the link to redirect to Repository page,so that when I login, I can see only the documents i.e Data Dictionary, User Homes?. I have noticed that when i login using the username and password and on click of login button, the Rest Url is "share/page/dologin". In this dologin file the link to the Dashboard is mentioned. But I dont know the mapping of Dologin. Can Anyone help?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify site-index.jsp (in the root of the share webapp) to redirect to the document library instead of the user's dashboard.

Change the line

`response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/user/" + URLEncoder.encode(userid) + "/dashboard");`

to

`response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/repository");`

This should redirect everyone to the repository page on login.

Comment: I am using sdk4, where I need to place site-indec.jsp file?